# Automatic link detector (PHP + RegEx)

Tags: php, regex, function, hyperlink, detect

I've created a function that automatically detects links. It works quite fine, except when a HTML tag begins just after a link (without space).

Example :

```
http://www.google.com is cool
```

becomes

```
&lt;a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"&gt;www.google.com&lt;/a&gt; is cool
```

but

```
http://www.google.com&lt;br />is cool
```

(without space after http:// in real) becomes

```
&lt;a href="http://www.google.com&lt;br /" target="_blank"&gt;www.google.com&lt;br /&lt;/a&gt; is cool
```

My regular expression doesn't stop at first `<`, though `<` is not allowed...

How can I fix that ? Or how can I exclude `<` efficiently ?

Here's my function :

```
function detect_linkg($str){        
    return preg_replace('#(https?://)([\w\d.&:\#@%/;$~_?\+-=]*)#','<a href="$1$2" target="_blank">$2</a>',$str);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here: `+-=`

This actually creates a range, like `a-z`, but in this case from `+` to `=`, and if you look at the [ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) chart you see that that includes `<` (but not `>`).

Simply escape `-` if you want the literal: `+\-=`

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution !